# SQL count query returning number of rows preset as 1 instead of actual number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

Below is PHP code from where I'm fetching a number of rows in a database table. But following code is returning a number of rows as 1 always. Please help me solve the problem to fetch the correct number of rows from the database.

```
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");               
     echo "<div class='row text-center col-lg-12' align='center'>";     
    $cmd="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search_query%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $cmd);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: have you tried running the same query in the sql section of phpmyadmin  for example or directly into mysql? If so what does it return?

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is the count of rows (as 1 row). Select the value... or return all the rows and then use the `num_rows` function. You should also parameterize the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` you will get a row back where the counted value is in the first column. So you need to get the `COUNT()` value like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $cmd);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");               
     echo "<div class='row text-center col-lg-12' align='center'>";     
    $cmd="SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search_query%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $cmd);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```